# angular2: Can't bind to 'x' since it isn't a known property of 'y'

Tags: angular

I'm using angular 2.3.0. I'm getting the next message:

> Can't bind to 'type' since it isn't a known property of 'alert'.

Template related code is (complete template code on [here](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/ae367c7742c399172d93059f7f1a2e34)):

```
<alert *ngFor="let alert of alerts; let i = index" [type]="alert.type + ' alert-sm'" (close)="closeAlert(i)" dismissible="true">
    <div [innerHTML]="alert.msg"></div>
</alert>
```

As you can guess, I'm getting each `alert` from `alerts` property.

Component related code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'signin',
  styleUrls: [ './signin.style.scss' ],
  templateUrl: './signin.template.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  host: {
    class: 'signin-page app'
  },
  providers: [ UsersService ]
})
export class Signin implements OnInit {

    private alerts: Array<Object>;

    constructor()
    {
        this.alerts = [
        {
            type: 'success',
            msg: '<span class="fw-semi-bold">Success:</span> You successfully read this important alert message.'
        }];
    }
}
```

I don't quite to figure out what's wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: what is `<alert></alert>`. i think you forgot to define `@Input() type: sring` in it. share component code if possible .

Comment: alert in an html tag located on component template. Component code is on post. Do you need something more?

Comment: i mean share code of `<alert></alert>` component not where you have used it.

Comment: I've create a gist with all template code on [here](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/ae367c7742c399172d93059f7f1a2e34)

Answer (score 1):

Change you HTML as below :

```
<div *ngFor="let alert of alerts; let i = index" [attr.type]="alert.type + ' alert-sm'" (close)="closeAlert(i)" dismissible="true">
    <div [innerHTML]="alert.msg"></div>
</div>
```